# Updating dynamic table using a edit button

Tags: php, mysql

I already have a dynamic table that generates a result from a database.

Now I want to make an update, how it works is when the btn update was click a form should enable the user to update the infos from ID, case, name document and date...

The problem I'm getting crazy is assume the ID is my PK and it's $ID how can I manage to get the $ID of a specific row when it is looping? Also should it be on the same webpage or should i write another page for the update?

```
 ID|    Case|  Name| Document| Date       Edit
 ----------------------------------------------
 1     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1   btn
 2     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1   btn
 3     233    alex    NULL     0000-0-0
 4     234    ben     COC      2015-3-3
 5     234    ben     VAT      2015-3-3
 6     234    ben     NULL     0000-0-0
```

This is my script:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("1xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","export_workflow") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
     if($link->connect_errno){
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
     } 
     //consultation: 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ORIGINAL_DEADLINE > current_date;"; 
     //execute the query. 
     if($result = $link->query($query)){
           echo "<table class='table_style' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";
          }
          $result->close();
          echo "</table>\r\n";
        } else {
          printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: yup not much experience, How ill i get the looping value of id so I can use a query

Answer (score 0):

You can pass related row's `ID` to the edit page. For example,

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=". $row['ID'] . "'> EDIT </a></td>";
```

Then get the `id` in `edit.php` page and on next page you could use form which submits data to `doedit.php` page. something like this,

```
<form action="doedit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" >
    <input type="text" name="field1" >
    ....
    All other input fields.
    ...
</form>
```

`doedit.php` have update query to update data in database.

Comment: I have a ID column as a primary key.

Comment: this is my code where the ID is getting wrong . <html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/form_style.css">
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="update.php">
<div class="form-style-6" id="dynamicField">
<h1>Edit Form</h1>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['ID'];?>" >

Comment: Are you sure you have passed `ID` to this page via link ? `<a href="edit.php?id=2"> EDIT </a>` for example.

Comment: fixed it, should be  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" .. lower case